# How to backend filter exact field of model

Tags: python, django

I have model named Tittle and I wanted to filter its GET respond by the "genres->slug". I tried to use backend filter with
`filterset_fields = ("genres__slug",)`. But it is not doing what I thought. How can I filter it by the model Slug of the Genres?

views.py

```
class TitleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Title.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AdminModifyOrReadOnlyPermission,)
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_fields = ('genres',)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrieve':
            return ReadTitleSerializer
        return WriteTitleSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Title(models.Model):

    ... 

    genres = models.ManyToManyField(
        Genre,
        through='GenreTitle',
    )


class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Название жанра'
    )

    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='Слаг жанра'
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.slug


class GenreTitle(models.Model):
    title_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Title,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='genres_titles'
    )

    genre_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Genre,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='genres_title'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different filter class and implement that with field name filterset_class in API.
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html